# Is Jetpack Compose further in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

At present, I use XML layout file in Android Studio.

I have read the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup).

1:  Is Jetpack Compose further in Android Studio?

2:  Will Android Studio give up the XML layout file? If so, when will Android Studio do it?

Comment: What do you mean by further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Android Studio has two main types of distribution: Stable and Preview. You can have both versions in your machine. The Stable version is normally used for production projects once it uses stable APIs and tools. The Preview version, on the other hand,  provides early access to new features. Therefore, once Compose is still in Beta (currently is beta 3), makes sense have to use a preview version of Android Studio.
2. Android UI development uses XML files since version 1.0, so it's expected that Android Studio provides support for XML layouts for a very long time. Besides, it's possible to have projects using both XML and Compose to create the UI.